# Subtraction of column by column, by a single element

Tags: r

I need to do a subtraction of two objects, but I don't get the expected result

```
library(matrixStats)
A<-matrix(c(5, 7, 4, 1, 14, 3), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow=T, 
        dimnames=list(c("Blanco", "Negro", "Rojo"), c("Toyota", "Audi")))

> A
       Toyota Audi
Blanco      5    7
Negro       4    1
Rojo       14    3

mx <- colMaxs(A)

> mx
[1] 14  7

A-mx

           Toyota Audi
Blanco     -9    0
Negro      -3  -13
Rojo        0   -4
```

What I want is that the maximum number is subtracted with its corresponding column, like this:

```
          Toyota Audi
Blanco     -9    0
Negro      -10  -6
Rojo        0   -4
```

The error in in the row "Negro". It's inverted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520720/subtract-a-constant-vector-from-each-row-in-a-matrix-in-r or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643555/multiply-rows-of-matrix-by-vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do:

```
t(t(A)-mx)
#      Toyota Audi
#Blanco     -9    0
#Negro     -10   -6
#Rojo        0   -4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `sweep`, which, by default subtracts out ("sweeps") values across a margin:

```
sweep(A, 2, colMaxs(A))
       Toyota Audi
Blanco     -9    0
Negro     -10   -6
Rojo        0   -4
```

---

Completely with base R, use, `apply` instead of `colMaxs`:

```
sweep(A, 2, apply(A, 2, max))
```

This may be a bit slower.

---

An alternative uses `rep` to repeat the max values and performs a vectorized operation.

```
A - rep(colMaxs(A), each=nrow(A))
```

or

```
A - rep(apply(A, 2, max), each=nrow(A))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
apply(A, 2, function(x) x - max(x))
#       Toyota Audi
#Blanco     -9    0
#Negro     -10   -6
#Rojo        0   -4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an lapply if you want to first turn your matrix into a data.table:

```
dt <- as.data.table(A)
dt[, (colnames(dt)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x - max(x)), .SDcols=colnames(dt)]
```

Comment: No need for `.SDcols=colnames(dt)` if you're using all the columns