# I have a table consists of many samples across many columns, how to substract the value of each sample in each column to the mean of their column?

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

Let's assume that I have this table called (GE_Table):

```
        Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
Sample1   5     4     9
Sample2   6     7     2
Sample3   10    5     3
```

To calculate the mean of every column, I make this code:

```
(colMeans(GE_Table[sapply(GE_Table, is.numeric)]))
```

****MY question is how to substract the numbers of let's say first column to the mean of this column and then the numbers of the second columns to the mean of this "second column" and so on?

Comment: See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520720/subtract-a-constant-vector-from-each-row-in-a-matrix-in-r/24520943

Comment: Thank you so much @thelatemail